# What kind of logics satisfy the coincidence lemma?

Tags: logic, model-theory

Lets formulate the incidence lemma as follows. We have
a possibly infinite set of variables X and the domain of 
discourse U. Lets define an interpretation of the variables
X in the domain U as a function:

$\sigma$ : X $\mapsto$ U

Let $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ be two interpretations of the
variables. Now if I have a formula A and also some 
interpretation of the function symbols, constants and 
relation symbols, I can say:

**Coincidence Lemma**: If $\sigma_1(x)$ = $\sigma_2(x)$ for all x 
occuring free in A, then A has the same truth value in both
interpretations $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$.

Are there any logics that violate this lemma? Any logics
that violate this lemma if we correspondingly look at the 
function symbols or constants or relation symbols occuring 
in the formula A?

P.S.: I have loosely translated the name of the lemma
from here:
Lemma 1.13: Koinzidenzlemma
Beweise und Programme. Anmerkungen zu
Heytings Formalisierung der intuitionistischen Logik
Helmut Schwichtenberg
See also:
http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koinzidenzlemma

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then failure to satisfy the lemma would mean that there's something wrong with your definition of "occurring free in $A$", more than it says anything intrinsic about the logic as a formal system.

Comment: Yeah, possibly we could define occuring free in A after the fact semantically and not before the fact syntactically, by virtue of this lemma.

Comment: If sigma is not an interpretation, but a simultaneous non-ground substitution, then the lemma doesn't hold. Right? Is there some logic that would amount to that?

Comment: x @Cookie: I don't follow that. Could you give a concrete counterexample?

Comment: Take p(x). Usually the truth value of the above sentence only depends on the interpretation of p and the domain value of x. But what if we allow to determine the truth to perform simultaneous non-ground substitutions?

Comment: Then the truth can depend on more than only p and x. For example if I substitute f(y) for x, and in one case a for y and in another case b for y. I could get different truth values.

Comment: x @Cookie: Oh, I see.